# What does ! mean in XPath 3.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-3.0

XPath 3.0 defines a new operator called the '[**mapping operator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator)'. It is denoted by the exclamation mark --`!`.

What does `A!B` mean? How do we use the `!` operator? Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple map operator (!)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator) works rather like /, except there is no restriction that the left hand operand must be a node-set, and there is no sorting of results into document order.

For example, `(1 to 7)!(.*.)` returns the sequence `(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49)`.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `(1 to 7)!(.*., .+.)` returns `(1, 2, 4, 4, 9, 6, 16, 8, 25, 10, 36, 12, 49, 14)`?

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your explanation. I wonder if there is any software that can evaluate XPath 3.0? I wish to test out its various new features.

Comment: @Davio Yes, Davio, exactly! Chong Lip Phang: You can test XPath 3.0 online e.g. http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: Most of the products that support XPath 3.0 also support XQuery 3.0, which is a superset. Examples are Saxon and BaseX.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example:

```
let $s := "The Taming of the Shrew"
return tokenize($s, ' ')!(string-length(.)||upper-case(.))
```

returns ("3THE", "6TAMING", "2OF", "3THE", "5SHREW")

This also uses the new string concatenation operator "||".